# How to read the absolute load address of the beginning of shared library data section on runtime?

Tags: c, linker, shared-libraries, linker-scripts, position-independent-code

## Lets consider this example:

glob.c source code is linked to shared library named glob.so. From main.c that link against glob.so I want to read the value of 'global_offset' variable at runtime(I don't think it's possible to do at compile time). My compiler is gcc 4.8.5 MinGW.

### glob.c:

```
int glob_shared_var = 69;
```

### main.c:

```
size_t global_offset = // read shared library load offset
size_t relative_glob_shared_var_offset = // read offset value from e.g. nm glob.a symbols table

printf("glob_shared_var value: %d \n", *(int *)(global_offset + relative_glob_shared_var_offset));
```

### console output:

```
glob_shared_var value: 69
```

Comment: If you want to access the variable from a different compilation unit (or a library), declare it as `extern glob_shared_var;` somewhere in main.c before using it. This kind of declaration is usually done in header files.

Comment: @dratenik I made a typo. I changed it to 'glob.so'. But your response does not answer my question about the global_offset address

Comment: The question makes little sense (you shouldn't want to know this) and the one use-case can be achieved better by different means. So why do you need to know this?

Comment: Are you asking the numerical value of the pointer of such variable? You will know it only at runtime. Library will be loaded randomly, and the linker will adapt the addresses.

Comment: If you want some system-dependent crazy hack, you can examine /proc/self/maps on Linux for example.

Comment: @dratenik I want to read the image/blob of the entire data section for my external tool. Also I want to have the ability to modify symbol values that way so I could restore application state. It allready work for static libraries but with shared libraries you can imagine it is a little bit more complicated.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Yes this is exactly what I want. And I don't want only the address of one symbol but the entire data segment. I know it can be know only at runtime but how to get it?

Comment: @dratenik Sorry I forgot to metion that I need it in MinGW on Windows. But thanks I will check it out. Maybe it will give me a clue

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I read little bit more about GNU LD linker scripts and I learned about `__data_start__` and `__data_end__` symbols which are added to the beginning and ending of each consolidated binary by default. What I guess could work is create custom linker script rule that creates `__data_start_glob__` and `__data_end_glob__` symbols accordingly next to them to uniquely identify each shared library while producing them.

After library creation I would produce text file dump from it and grep offset addresses of each symbol in the library and put it to simple flat text file which will be then read at runtime.

reading address of shared library data section at runtime would look like this:

```
usize_t = glob_offset = &__data_start_glob__;

usize_t = glob_shared_var_offset; // read from flat file 

int val = *(int *)(glob_offset + glob_shared_var_offset);
```

I know that use-case for this will be very limited, but maybe someone will have similar crazy idea in the future.